# How MongoDB refs works internally?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I am really confused about

> ' How document of other collection is stored in a document?'.

Does ref just keep the address of the document and populate on demand in O(1) or it stores like a relational DB and search throughout the table to get the relevant document?

e.g We have two collections, User and Posts.

```
User {
_id: mongoId of User,
name: String,
post: reference of post id
  
}

Post {
_id: mongoId of Post,
title: String,
body: String
}
```

Now, Users stores Post in form of a reference. While fetching the document which is posted by a particular user, will it go through all the documents in post and fetch the one which is relevant to us or it just store the direct reference to that document and fetch in O(1).

Comment: Does this help: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/#database-references

Comment: I read this document earlier. But, It doesn't explain exactly how they store documents with relation at low level .